# Assign type to JSON type that might not need to be parsed

Tags: typescript, tsc, typescript3.0

I have this bit of code. Common problem where I can't always remember if the API returns JSON or parsed object.

```
  github.repos.getForOrg({org}, (err: any, res: any) => {

      if (err) {
        return cb(err, null);
      }

      try {
        res = <Array<{ clone_url: string }>>JSON.parse(res);
      }
      catch (err) {
        // ignore
      }


      const cloneUrls = res.map(item => item.clone_url);

  });
```

The problem, however, is that it recognizes that it's an an array, but it won't commit to the type of the element in the array. It might be a TS bug, not sure, seems strange though that it would accept that it's an array, but not admit to knowing the type of the elements?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Since `res` is of type `any`, TypeScript will allow any method name (including `map`) to be called on it with any arguments.  By annotating `res` with type `any`, you have indicated that you want this behavior for `res`.  Since the callback is bringing a new variable `item` into scope for the body, TypeScript gives you a `noImplicitAny` error to give you a fresh opportunity to decide whether you want the same loose behavior for operations on `item` as well.

Answer (score 1):

I would write it like this:

```
let result: Array<{ clone_url: string }> = null;
if (res.constructor === Array) {
    result = res as Array<{ clone_url: string }>;
} else if (typeof res === 'string') {
    result = JSON.parse(res) as Array<{ clone_url: string}>;
} else {
    throw Error('unexpected type for github repo list response, neither array nor string');
}
```

After that use `result` instead of `res`.